# How to make the button loads the previous page in Android?

Tags: java, android

I have search a lot in different sites to solve this problem but I can't till now.

I have a simple app with 50 articles, two buttons, previous and next.

All works fine till the last article 50 where the problem is that the user can't choose the previous button 49, only can load from the beginning.

Here is my code: `MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView meditCenterText;
private Button mStartButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    meditCenterText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editCenterText);
    mStartButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);

    meditCenterText.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

    mStartButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String TextView = meditCenterText.getText().toString();
            startStory(TextView);

        }
    });
}

private void startStory(String TextView) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, StoryActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("TextView", TextView);
    startActivity(intent);
}





@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    meditCenterText.setText("..... ");
}}
```

**StoryActivity.java**

```
public class StoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String TAG = StoryActivity.class.getSimpleName();


private Story mStory = new Story();

private ImageView mImageView;
private TextView mTextView;
private Page mCurrentPage;
private String mName;
private Button mPreviousButton;
private Button mNextButton;
private ScrollView mScrollView;
private Button mStartButton;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_story2);

  //Intent intent = getIntent();
   //mName = intent.getStringExtra(getString(R.string.key_name));

    if(mName == null){
        mName = "";
    }

    Log.d(TAG, mName);

    mImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.storyImageView);
    mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.storyTextView);
   mPreviousButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.previousButton);
   mNextButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.nextButton);

    mTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

    loadPage(0);
}
private void loadPage(int choice){
 mCurrentPage = mStory.getPage(choice);

    Drawable drawable  = getResources().getDrawable(mCurrentPage.getImageId());
    mImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);

    String pageText = mCurrentPage.getText();
    //add the name if placeholder included.
   //pageText  = String.format(pageText,mName);
    mTextView.setText(pageText);

    if(mCurrentPage.isSingle()){
        mPreviousButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mNextButton.setText("Start From The Beginning");
        mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mPreviousButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                loadPage(0);
            }
        });

    }else{

        mPreviousButton.setText(mCurrentPage.getChoices().getText1());
        mNextButton.setText(mCurrentPage.getChoices().getText2());

        mPreviousButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int previousPage = mCurrentPage.getChoices().getPreviousPage();
                loadPage(previousPage);
            }
        });

        mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int nextPage = mCurrentPage.getChoices().getNextPage();
            loadPage(nextPage);



        }
    });
}}
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Two buttons in different activity?

Comment: No. OP uses two buttons in same activity.

Comment: You're making the `mPreviousButton` visible in one branch of the `if` but set up its `onClick` in the `else` branch. That doesn't look right. - In fact, why not set up the `onClick` listeners in `onCreate`?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. Could you write to me what is wrong on the clickListener?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the logic in your Page class. Have a proper look at it, otherwise from the android side everything is alright. One last thing, you should probably use a `ViewPager` for your app instead of changing the text every time you load a new oage

Comment: Hi Niza, Thanks for your answer. Below I post my code of Page class to have a look, unfortunatelly can't figure it out. For the viewPager you told me should be deleted something and re-write with the way of viewPager? Haven't use it before.

Comment: public class Page {

    private int mPageId;
    private int mImageId;
    private String mText;
    private Choices mChoices;
    private boolean mIsSingle = false;

    public Page(int pageId, int imageId, String text, Choices choices) {

        mPageId = pageId;
        mImageId = imageId;
        mText = text;
        mChoices = choices;
    }

    public Page(int pageId, int imageId, String text) {

        mPageId = pageId;
        mImageId = imageId;
        mText = text;
        mChoices = null;
        mIsSingle = true;
    }

Comment: public int getPageId(){
        return mPageId;
    }

    public void setPageId(int pageId){
        mPageId = pageId;
    }

    public int getImageId() {
        return mImageId;
    }

    public void setImageId(int imageId) {
        mImageId = imageId;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return mText;
    }

    public void setText(String text){
        mText = text;
    }

Comment: public Choices getChoices(){
        return mChoices;
    }

    public void setChoices(Choices choices){
        mChoices = choices;
    }

        public boolean isSingle() {

            return mIsSingle;
        }

        public void setSingle(boolean isFinal) {

            mIsSingle = isFinal;
        }
      }